# getting error when retrieving connections using linkedin api in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application where i am integrating linkedin in my app.I want to fetch the connections of the logged in user.For  this i have done the code but it is returning error:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Unknown authentication scheme",
  "requestId": "98TKWP0T23",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1355726431107
}
```

This is the code that i have done:-

```
(NSMutableArray*) getFriendsList
{      
  NSString *url1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=%@:(connections)?format=application/json",linkedinid];
  NSLog(@"%@",url1);
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url1];

  OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] 
                                         initWithURL:url
                                            consumer:consumer
                                               token:token
                                            callback:nil
                                            signatureProvider:nil];
  [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

   NSError *err;
   NSURLResponse *resp;
   NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&resp error:&err];
   NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   if (response != nil)
   {
     NSString *stringResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
     NSDictionary *linkedin_response = [parser objectWithString:stringResponse error:nil];   
   }    
}
```

but in the stringresponse it is returning the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
- (void)getFriendsList
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections"];
   OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                consumer:oAuthLoginView.consumer
                                   token:oAuthLoginView.accessToken
                                callback:nil
                       signatureProvider:nil];

   [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];

   OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
   [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(networkApiCallResult:didFinish:)
              didFailSelector:@selector(networkApiCallResult:didFail:)];    
}

- (void)networkApiCallResult:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinish:(NSData *)data
{
   NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
   NSDictionary *demo = [responseBody objectFromJSONString];


   NSMutableArray *connections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   for(int i=0;i<[[demo objectForKey:@"_count"] intValue];i++)
   {
      NSDictionary *person = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[[[responseBody objectFromJSONString] 
                                                                  objectForKey:@"values"] 
                                                                 objectAtIndex:i]
                                                                objectForKey:@"firstName"],[[[[responseBody objectFromJSONString] 
                                                                                              objectForKey:@"values"] 
                                                                                             objectAtIndex:i]
                                                                                            objectForKey:@"lastName"]];
      NSLog(@"Connection %d : %@",i,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[[[responseBody objectFromJSONString] 
                                                                         objectForKey:@"values"] 
                                                                        objectAtIndex:i]
                                                                       objectForKey:@"firstName"],[[[[responseBody objectFromJSONString] 
                                                                                                     objectForKey:@"values"] 
                                                                                                    objectAtIndex:i]
                                                                                                   objectForKey:@"lastName"]]);
     [connections addObject:person];  
   }
}

- (void)networkApiCallResult:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFail:(NSData *)error 
{
   NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
}
```

Comment: Hi @abi_anarchy95 i have added u r code but the networkapiCallResult selector method is not getting called

Comment: @Rani does the method fetchDataWithRequest getting called??

Comment: Hi @abi_anarchy95 no the method fetchDatawithRequest is not getting called

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, you are not passing up the "Username / Password" in the post, and as such you are getting the "Unknown authentication scheme". I am unsure if you would be able to detect in your own app the connections of the logged in user, unless you are storing their credentials inside your app.

Comment: yes i am storing the username of the logged in user in my app but should i pass the username to url

Comment: it is not mentioned in the api to pass username /password of the loggedinuser

Comment: You are most likely correct... I don't have a ton of experience with the LinkedIn API. I will see if I can look tomorrow.